# Get data from Amazon redshift in web2py

Tags: database-connection, web2py, amazon-redshift

How do I connect Amazon-redshift database with Web2Py. I tried connecting using Postgres connection strings as Amazon-redshift is based on Postgres.

> postgres://username:password@examplecluster..us-west redshift.amazonaws.com/dbname

This is not working.